# Whether using present or past simple in the imaginary past event

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals, if, imaginary-situations

> I might have thought she __ not able to speak, if I had not heard
> her singing.

It's just a made-up sentence, please apologize if it doesn't make sense. Anyway, if only if I have to choose between **is** and **were/was**, putting aside the other possiblity, what should I put in there?

I'm also requesting the other possibility if there's any or explaining whether it's grammatical or not, but please after telling me which one is better between **is** and **were/was**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Was" is used in the first person singular (I) and the third person singular (he, she, it).

"Were" is used in the second person singular and plural (you, your, yours) and first and third person plural (we, they).

> *I* **was** driving to the park.

> *You* **were** drinking some water.

In this case, a third person singular is being used, "she", so you say it like this

> I might have thought she was not able to speak, if I had not heard her singing.

Read more on [Was vs Were and many examples](https://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference#:%7E:text=Forms%20of%20Was%20and%20Were&text=Was%20is%20used%20in%20the,plural%20(we%2C%20they).&text=I%20was%20driving%20to%20the,You%20were%20drinking%20some%20water.)